# how to get the my added hidden fields in paypal ipn?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am getting stuck on this. i am not getting  my these two hidden fields rest of i get all data. Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong. Here is my paypal form:-

```
<form id="paypalForm" action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" target="_blank" name="paypalform" method="post" style="display: none;" >
 <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID; ?>">
 <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
 <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{ $serviceName }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $cartId; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
 <input type="hidden" name="auto_renew" value="no">
 <input type="hidden" name="email_pref" value="no">
 <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value="{{ url('/ipn-paypal-success') }}">
 <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value="{{ url('/paypal-cancel') }}">
 <input type='hidden' name='return' value="{{ url('/paypal-sucess') }}">
 <div class="form-group">
     <label  class="col-xs-3 col-form-label"></label>
     <div class="col-xs-9">
         <input id="paypalsubmit" type="button" value="Proceed to Payment"  class="btn btn-payment-btn" /> 
     </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Here is my new two hidden fields are auto_renew and email_pref
But when i get response in email i don't get these two. here is my Ipn function:-

```
public function ipnPaypalSucess(){
    $data = $_REQUEST;
    mail('my-test-email@gmail.com', 'array data', '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>');    
}
```

I am using laravel 5.2 framework. Please help me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

The content and order of `$_REQUEST` is affected by `variables_order` directive in php.ini

Why you don't use Laravel Request?

be sure there is `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` top of controller

```
public function ipnPaypalSucess(Request $request){
    return $request->all();
}
```

if all input fields displayed so replace your code with :

```
public function ipnPaypalSucess(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    mail('my-test-email@gmail.com', 'array data', '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add your own fields to a PayPal button and expect those fields to come back in IPN.  There is a single field that's meant for this, and it's literally called "custom".  So this is what you would need to do:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="custom value(s) go here" />
```

Whatever you place in that field would then come back in `$_REQUEST['custom']` in your IPN listener.

When you have multiple fields you could place an NVP string in the custom parameter and then parse it back out within the IPN script.  Alternatively, you could store all your custom data in your database, and then pass a record ID in the custom parameter so that you can then pull that data back out based on the record ID within the IPN script.